# Why does $form['_csrf_token']->render(); render a hidden input without a value in symfony 1.4.8?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I using symfony 1.4.8 and when trying to render the hidden csrf form field a value is not being added to the rendered field. I've done this before without issue. See the following to examples below to see the code and the rendered output.

Code:

```
<?php echo $form['_csrf_token']->render(); ?>
```

Generates:

```
<input type="hidden" name="contact[_csrf_token]" id="contact__csrf_token" />
```

---

Code:

```
<?php echo $form['_csrf_token']->renderRow(); ?>
```

Generates:

```
<tr>
  <th><label for="contact__csrf_token"> csrf token</label></th>
  <td><input type="hidden" name="contact[_csrf_token]" value="3cf960d4553e2649f86d0ccd12a26efe" id="contact__csrf_token" /></td>
</tr>
```

---

As you can see the second method generates the value for the csrf_token, but it also generates all the other row information. The `render()` method is supposed to just generate the 'widget' (in this case the hidden input field) with the value. For some reason it does not add a value.

Comment: I have had the same problem recently. The problem was that I have forgotten to check if the request method is post before I call form's bind method. Avoid calling form->bind() if form is not submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to explicitly render it? Why are you not using `$form->renderHiddenFields()` ?

Comment: I was initially using `$form->renderHiddenFields()`, but was having the same error. I decided to cut away the rest of the fluff and render just the _csrf_token which I was having a problem with.

Comment: Although not what was troubling me this will probably be the most useful answer for the next person looking up this issue.

Comment: I used $form->renderHiddenFields() but get same error anyway. Did you found a workaround to fix this? I do not want to do a page refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$form->renderHiddenFields()` instead.

Comment: See my response to Dziamid above.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a hard refresh. Something is stuck in your session.

Hard refresh is Shift+F5

If that fails, delete all your domain cookies for your domain and try again.

It is simply a session issue, provided you've not messed with csrf elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are some many different reasons for this behavior in symfony:

- Do not use *bind* before process form validation.
- Session time is over and there is no session id.
- CSRF Validation is disabled or have not being set a *csrf_secret* value in *settings.yml* file

I present a quick solution to get CSRF Token value directly printed:

```
<input type="hidden" name="signin[_csrf_token]" id="signin__csrf_token" value="<?php echo $form->getCSRFToken(); ?>" />
```

Using:

```
$form->getCSRFToken();
```

will render a new generated CSRF Token.